# ASP.NET app can't open Kestrel

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-code, dnx, kestrel-http-server

We're trying to write ASP.NET applications on a Mac using VSCode. We have successfully installed VSCode, DNX, Yeoman, Node.js and npm, and permutations of everything else mentioned in [the ASP.NET guide](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/your-first-mac-aspnet.html). After creating a sample application with Yo, restoring dependencies, and even building with no errors, running the application with "dnx web" Returns an error.

> System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions.IAssemblyLoadContextAccessor' from assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.

([Full stack trace](http://hastebin.com/moguginofe.xml))

We get this error specifically when running "dnx web" from the command line or through VSCode's "dnx run command", and both with dnx 1.0.0-rc1-update1 and the latest update (rc2-16595, I believe)

I think this is a versioning problem in our Kestrel setup -  our project (dnu build)s properly, just the test breaks while it loads. Any ideas?

Comment: You are mixing versions. RC1 does not mix well with RC2. I would recommend sticking to rc1-final or rc1-update1 for the time being. If you want to go with rc2 I would recommend dotnet instead of dnx since dnx is being retired in favor of dotnet.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem above on OS X v10.11.x.

Step 1: Make sure, you run this command:
 $ dnvm list

Step 2: Change to the correct version.
E.g on my machine, I changed
$ dnvm use 1.0.0-rc1-update2 -r mono

Good luck!